# Sharing a loss variable between two optimizers, am I doing this correctly?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I have a training loop that trains two neural networks; one generator (optimizer_BaN) and one classification network (optimizer). I want to use the loss term `backdoor_loss` for both optimizers. I ran into some errors suggesting that I need to retain the graph for the first `.backward` call. My code now works, but I don't fully grasp how my code works, therefore I don't know for sure if I implemented this correctly. If I understood correctly, the `.backward` call computes the gradients, `retain_graph=True` prevents `.backward` from deleting the computational graph needed to compute the loss (since we need it to calculate `total_loss`), and `.step` applies the gradients, thereby adjusting the weights. Have I implemented this correctly? I am asking this because the `uniqueness_loss` won't lower during training, and I want to be able to rule out this possible cause.

```
    optimizer_BaN.zero_grad()
    BaN_loss = alpha * backdoor_loss + (1 - alpha) * uniqueness_loss
    BaN_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
    optimizer_BaN.step()

    optimizer.zero_grad()
    total_loss = beta * clean_loss + (1 - beta) * backdoor_loss
    total_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

I tried reading other posts on stackoverflow, but I don't think I fully understand yet.

Comment: Why dont you just combined 2 loss?